# error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'. what does this error mean?

Tags: java, binary

```
   if(root1==null && root2==null) return true ;
    if(((root1!=null) && (root2!=null ))&& (root1.val==root2.val)){
        return (isMirror(root1.left,root2.right)&&isMirror(root2.left && root1.right));
    }
```

**strong text**        return false;

I'm getting error in the second if clause statement.
Please Help me out.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `isMirror` method parameters. You have passed  `isMirror(root2.left && root1.right)`  this should be `isMirror(root2.left, root1.right)`

```
if(root1==null && root2==null) return true ;
if(((root1!=null) && (root2!=null ))&& (root1.val==root2.val)){
    return (isMirror(root1.left,root2.right)&&isMirror(root2.left, root1.right));
}
```